# Possible to use Azure Application Gateway and Azure Firewall on AKS?

Tags: firewall, azure, web-application-firewall

I have an AKS cluster running on Azure (managed Kubernetes). I'd like to put a WAF in front of it, using Azure Web Application Gateway. I *think* this is possible.

But I also want a firewall in front of it, to limit both inbound and outbound traffic. I don't see any documentation on how to combine both an application gateway and a firewall in Azure.

Is this possible? And is this possible using AKS? I tried to get the Application Gateway working on AKS but didn't succeed, I always get a 502 meaning the gateway can't reach the backend pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can put application gateway in front of aks. just use internal load balancer as a balancing mechanism for your services and point properly configured application gateway at it. To use internal load balancer you have to create a service similar to this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: name
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
spec:
  ports:
  - port: port
  selector:
    app: something
  type: LoadBalancer
```

I dont think you need Azure Firewall, you need Network Security Group (NSG). You can use NSG together with Application gateway, but there are some restrictions you have to keep in mind.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq#configuration

Overall - yes, this is possible

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I already tried with the internal load balancer butI can't get it working so I was wondering if it is even possible. I'll try further then!

Comment: the only reason for internal LB so that its not accessible from outside, you dont necessary have to use it, just makes more sense

Comment: well yes, and you need an ip to configure the backendpool of the gateway, I just can't get it to reach it.

Comment: you can use external ip as an endpoint :) just make sure that LB routes traffic to nodes and nodes really listen on that port, so just test internal LB without application gateway and then when you get it working point appgw to that lb, make sure that the probe is configured properly

Comment: I used the internal lb ip as endpoint instead of the k8s services, I presumed they were the same. I added the service ip now and it works :)